# Can't go in another view using storyboardWithName

Tags: ios, storyboard

Using storyboards i have a tab bar controller with 2 views. In one view i want to have the ability to send the user in another view if is not logged in.

Show in the FirstView i have this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(![self loggedin])
    {
        ErrorView *wizard =  (ErrorView*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iphone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wizard"];
        [wizard setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
        [self presentViewController:wizard animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    .....
```

If the user is not logged in i'am getting this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any help will be very appreciable.

Comment: Although, Gavin's answer will do the job, check a full solution for login/logout actions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear`, the current view controller is not yet visible, hence why it says it *will* appear, not *did* appear. You can fix it by moving your code to the `viewDidAppear` method.