# ios dismiss a controller and present a controller with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a root view controller that presents an authentication view controller. Once the user authenticates I need to dismiss the authentication controller and present a user specific controller (example: on boarding controller, normal user controller, pro user controller). What I would like to happen is when the authentication controller is animated down, the appropriate controller is revealed (as if it was presented before the authentication controller).

These are the two solutions I have tried so far. Both show the root view controller between transitions.

1. In the `-viewDidAppear` of the root view controller I present the appropriate controller (authentication or user specific controller).
2. I have tried to dismiss and present the two controllers using the following:

   ```
   [authenticationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:<NO|YES> completion:^{
       [userController presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:nil];
   }];
   ```

TLDR:

I have a modal view hierarchy that starts like this `rootViewController->viewController1` and I want to transition to `rootViewController->viewController2` where `viewController1` animates down to reveal `viewController2`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou/21877460#21877460 maybe helps you, covers the whole concept of login process.

Comment: Its not quite what I am looking for. That solution knows what the users root controller should look like. In my example I am unsure what the user controller is going to be until after the authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is done authenticating set a flag of meaningful value to you then lets say once they hit OK or Submit you can check and set the flag.

From there you will instantiate one of the three view controllers and push it in the navigation stack - do this using the storyboard if you like by setting the storyboard ID to a value and then instantiate the VC with storyboard ID.

If you need more clarification or if this isn't the right track let me know.

A

EDIT : once you instantiate you will need to present the view controller with animation

Comment: This would mean the authentication controller is still part of the modal view hierarchy. That is what I am trying to avoid at all costs.

Comment: How about a forced segue to the next VC with an animation OR you can set your nav controller with all the views in a stack and just pop to the level you need (although that may not be what you want either...)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) for `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` states:

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack.

So one way to achieve that kind of behavior would be to arrange your view controllers like this:

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

You put the view controller `vc2` that you want to show *after* the login at the first position. In `vc2`'s `-viewWillAppear` method you forward to `vc1` in case the user is not logged in:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    if (!userLoggedIn) {
        UIViewController *vc1 = [[YourViewControllerClass1 alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:vc1  animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

When the user taps the `Show Login VC` button in `vc1` you present the login view controller from there:

```
- (IBAction)touchUpInsideShowLoginVCButton:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *loginVC = [[YourLoginViewControllerClass alloc] init];
    loginVC.delegate = self.presentingViewController;
    [self presentViewController:loginVC  animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You also set `vc2` as `loginVC`'s delegate here because you need a reference to `vc2` in your `loginVC`. (You need to define a property `delegate` in the .h file of `loginVC`:)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *delegate;
```

Finally, when the user taps the `Login` button and the login is successful you dismiss two view controllers at the same time (by simply calling `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on `vc2` which is the lowest in the hierarchy) in order to reveal `vc2` for the first time.

```
- (IBAction)touchUpInsideLoginButton:(id)sender {
    // ... your login code
    if (loginSuccessful) {
        [self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `presentViewController` don't support to insert a viewController below the top presentedViewController, which is the authentication controller here. If you have a navigationController for rootViewController, you can try `pushViewController:animated:` before   do dismiss authentication controller, and push animated can be NO;