# What is the best practice to continue flow after user authentication in iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my AppDelegate I check if there is already a user logged in.

```
if (userExists) {
        // Set my main view as the root view controller.
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
        [navController setRootViewController:mainVC animated:YES];
        [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
}
```

If there is no existing user I present a login screen.

Now, once the user has logged in I have to continue the flow, showing the `MainViewController`.

I am currently doing the following, in a block that gets called when the user is successfully authenticated:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[navController setRootViewController:wordViewController animated:YES];
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application.windows.firstObject setRootViewController:navController];
```

Is this a good way to go? Since this is a frequently repeated pattern throughout iOS apps, what is the most common, sensible way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for Storyboard login screen, handling clearing of data upon logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refactor the code that continues the flow when the user is authenticated. You can call it either immediately, or upon the successful login. For example:

```
 - (void)showMainScreenForUser:(UserType *)user
{
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithUser:user];
        [navController setRootViewController:mainVC animated:YES];
        [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
}
```

Comment: I presume that this should go in my AppDelegate, right?