# I'm trying to learn how to present a modal "login view" from anywhere in the app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure how to reuse a login view anywhere in my app...so when I click login on any screen I can just login and then have the view dismiss...I guess I'm not finding tutorial about modally displaying a common view across the entire app...

Comment: Are you using `UIStoryboard` ?

Comment: -1. Did you search enough?  I highly recommend that you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou) question, It's in Objective-C but the logic is EXACTLY the same. ALSO see this [SWIFT video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKXyLmYA0-c&list=PLoN_ejT35AEipRnSHSv5wlHGyjOnHReqx). Basically where ever you want you have to use `presentViewController` and then dismiss it after you're done with it.FYI login screens are *usually* to be presented modally... as they don't belong to the natural flow.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work.
Define you view in login view controller.
`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! UIViewController`

present whenever you want to show login screen.

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: do I have to do this in every one of my other viewcontrollers or can I do this at the app level somehow?

Comment: You can define this in a function in any utility file and call this. function whenever necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..(You can make single instance of loginViewController and use this code any where from app.)

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard  storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *loginViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
UIViewController *lastPresentedViewController =  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

while (lastPresentedViewController.presentedViewController) {
    lastPresentedViewController = lastPresentedViewController.presentedViewController;
}

[lastPresentedViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c".