# Parent view controller not dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue with the `presentViewController`function.

I have a login menu (A) and a button who display a login form (B). On success login, I present a third view with `self.presentViewController` (C).

Login menu (A) -> Login form (B) -> Content (C)

It's work, I can present the third view (C) but the login menu (A) is always visible (I can see it in UI Debug mod).

So, how to close the A ViewController?

Comment: After the login dismiss the present view controller in ->content (C)

Comment: Have you tried self.navigationController dismiss??

Comment: This is the way presentViewController works. If you are presenting B from A, It doesn't mean it will close the A. In you case if you want to "Content" to be rootController, Then you have to change window.rootviewcontroller = yourviewcontroller.

Comment: you may need to change the order of the hierarchy probably to a most logical one, like e.g. _Content_ (A) ➜ _Login Menu_ (B) ➜ _Login Form_ (C), so when you dismiss the to login forms and views, it falls back to the _Content_ (A) as it should be.

Comment: And if you want to go with more advance level coding, Then you can also use ContainerView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou Refer for best practices

Answer (score 1):

`presentViewController`, presents a view controller modally.  In other words, over the current view controller’s content, and the current view controller will not get deallocated.

Use the following code for your sample:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: <Identifier as in Storyboard of C>)
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController = vc
```

If you would like to include a transition, you could replace the last line with something as the following:

```
UIView.transition(from: currentRootViewController!.view, to: vc.view, duration: 0.8, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, completion: { (_) in
      (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController = vc
})
```

Comment: @YoannLth : This is the way you can change the root-controller

Comment: the OP's post seems to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), therefore you need to resolve problem X for him, not offering an overcomplicated solution for problem Y, maybe.

Comment: I tried with this answer @Wolverine but it didn't work. I fixed the problem with a dirty hack I think : I dismiss all view controllers with `self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerA‌​nimated(false, completion: nil)` and it return to the app entry point which is a ViewController who check if user is logged in.

Comment: @YoannLth, I simplified the solution as holex suggested.  I think the problem with my explanation for you was that I pointed towards the initialVC, whereas your C is probably not your initialVC.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the **presentVieController** mechanism, this is not a problem or bug. Still if you feel that you don not want your previous controller's remain in Hierarchy, Then you have to change the flow.

Currently your flow is :

A -> RootViewController.
B -> LoginScreen
C -> Container

I would suggest to refer below answer for best practise.

[Best practices for Storyboard login screen, handling clearing of data upon logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou)

if you give thoughts on handling the flow, you can solve your problem. here are my suggestions

**Suggestions** :

1. You set **C** as a rootController, In **C's ViewDidLoad** , you check weather User is logged in or not, If user is not logged in, you can present **A** , And From there you can present **B**. Once you successfully get logged in, you can dismiss **A** and **B** And refresh your rootController **C** as per logged user values.

To dismiss multiple view controller, you can try below code

```
-(void)dismissModalStack {
    UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
    while (vc.presentingViewController) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController;
    }
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

2. You can also use the **ContainerView** mechanism, You set **C** as rootController, And in **C** , you take an **ContainerView** In which you can show the **A** And **B** and after login, you can remove them and refresh **C**.

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial has your answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIaRs2d6Xm0