# AppDelegate segue alternative pass data

Tags: swift, segue, appdelegate, presentviewcontroller

I am struggling with passing data from my appDelegate to one of my view controllers. I have tried to use segues to do this, but this just doesn't work. So what I am wondering about is; is there any other way to present another view controller and pass data to it, other than using segues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only `segue` from a `viewController` to another. `AppDelegate` is NOT a viewController and therefore you **can't** segue You should either use delegation pattern or notifications. Or perhaps if you are using the wrong term. You can set your rootViewController

Comment: @Honey that's what I thought, thanks for clearing this up. However, could I possibly present the Viewcontroller through storyboard and then pass data?

Comment: I recommend seeing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou/21889172#21889172) It has a very easy design with good answers.

Comment: There is prepareForSegue, since you have no viewController to prepare from. Yet you can instantiate a viewController and then populate its properties/members and set as the `rootViewController` of your `navigationController`

Comment: @Honey Thanks! Do you happen to have any Swift examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use segue to `ViewController` from `AppDelegate`, because `AppDelegate` is not a `ViewController`. Segues are only work with `ViewControllers`.

But you can initiate a **storyboard identifier** from your `AppDelegate` to your `ViewController` so you can send data.

*There is a example for you;*

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let yourViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier") as! YourViewControllerClassName
        yourViewController.yourProperty = "yourValue"
        self.window?.rootViewController = yourViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

You can set your `Storyboard ID` in your `Main.storyboard`. Just select your `ViewController` and set storyboard ID section click the **Use Storyboard ID** checkmark like image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, with a little tweak in the code!

Comment: so happy coding :)