# How to display a specific ViewController in OneSignal Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, push-notification, onesignal

I do app with `OneSignal` and `Swift 3`. I got push. How to display a specific `ViewController` with `WebView` in `OneSignal` when notification is clicked. In push in additional data with field `"link"` I got link, but can't display this link in my `WebView`.

I try use global variable `tempURL` to put url from `additional data`. But it not work.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "MYID", handleNotificationAction: { (result) in
      let payload = result?.notification.payload
        print("This is Payload \(payload)")
        var fullMessage = payload?.title
        let messageTitle = "OneSignal Example"

        if (result?.action.actionID) != nil {
        let additionalData = payload?.additionalData
        let url = additionalData?["link"] as! String?
        tempURL = url!
        fullMessage =  fullMessage! + "\nPressed ButtonId:\(url)"

        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: messageTitle, message: fullMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.show(alertController, sender: nil)

     })
   return true
}
```

Try to show:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    let aViewController = ViewController()
    aViewController.loadAddressURL(url: tempURL)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(aViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

I have error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can't pass data in your way. You should instantiate `ViewController` with `StoryboardID`. I explained how to use it with [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578791/appdelegate-segue-alternative-pass-data/40578913#40578913)

If you are pretty sure, your additionalData is not nil, you can pass your data with **StoryboardID**.