# Swift iOS app how should I manage my ViewControllers in my app ?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new in Swift and I'm completely lost with how I should manage my ViewControllers :(

(I'm not using Storyboard and all the tutorials I understand are with storyboard...)

I have an app with 3 "main" ViewControllers that I manage with a tabBarController 
(in AppDelegate :)

```
self.tabBarController = TabBar() // TabBar is a UITabBarController object
self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabBarController
```

And I also have a few others ViewController (login page or my left menu for example) that I don't want to show in the tabBar.

But how should I manage my ViewControllers ? I tried with a UINavigationController but I don't understand how I'm supposed to setup this and how can I keep my tabBarController AND a NavigationController ?

Thanks !

Comment: Here you will find a lot of method to do so -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962276/best-practices-for-storyboard-login-screen-handling-clearing-of-data-upon-logou

Comment: And here is my custom implementation of Login singup with uitabbarcontroller - https://github.com/ajaysinghthakur/LoginApp