# blank collection view in user login for the first time

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, swiftui, swift5

Good day everyone,

I have root view controller set up as my **HomeViewController**, in this project i am using token based authentication ( which i am storing in user defaults ) and i am using token for all my API calls.

I have a check in my **viewWillAppear** method to check if there is access token present and then  i make the api call in **viewDidAppear** to populate the collection view, and this works perfectly fine at all times except the first time.

If I log in for the first time it hits the viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and then login screen pops up and once i authenticate the user and save it in the UserDefaults, dismiss the login screen and in the HomeViewController all i get is a spinner ( which means that **viewDidAppear** is also been called )  but if i close the app and open it again it all works fine.

What can i change in my code to make it work in the first time please and thank you!!

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
        
    // MARK: - Properties
        
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()            
    var publishedReportList: [ReportListDetail] = []
    
    private let reportsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let viewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: viewLayout)
        collectionView.register(ReportsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ReportsCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Initialisation
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        reportsCollectionView.delegate = self
        reportsCollectionView.dataSource = self

        print(publishedReportList.count)
                
        refreshControl.tintColor = .blue
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        reportsCollectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        reportsCollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    }
    
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)        
        // check auth status
        handleNotAuthenticated()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // call for reports
        getReportUserLayout()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Handlers
    
    @objc func pullToRefresh() {
       // Code to refresh table view
        getReportUserLayout()
    }
    
    fileprivate func getReportUserLayout() {
//        publishedReportList.removeAll()
        whySuchEmptyLabel.isHidden = true
        spinner.show(in: view)
        spinner.textLabel.text = "Loading Reports.."
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            ReportsManager.shared.getReportData { [weak self] (listOfReports) in
                
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                strongSelf.publishedReportList = listOfReports
                if listOfReports.count == 0 {
                    strongSelf.whySuchEmptyLabel.isHidden = false
                }
                strongSelf.reportsCollectionView.reloadData()
                strongSelf.spinner.dismiss()
                strongSelf.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleNotAuthenticated() {
        
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken") == nil {
            // show login view controller
            let loginVC = LoginViewController()
            loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            present(loginVC, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 - check for the token in `AppDelegate` 
2 - according to that set your root controller (home or login)
3 - possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19962276/10279508)

Answer (score 0):

You are in the `HomeViewController` and presenting `loginVC`, so it will not trigger `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` because it is not disappeared from the app. You have to use closure or delegate or notification to communicate back to the `HomeViewController`. You can also use the Combine framework and save the state. Here is an example of using delegate.

```
// Add protocol
protocol  ViewControllerDelegate {
    func loggedIn()
}
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {
    private func handleNotAuthenticated() {
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken") == nil {
            let loginVC = LoginViewController()
            loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            loginVC.viewDelegate = self
            present(loginVC, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
    

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewDelegate: ViewControllerDelegate? = nil
    
    func userLoggedIn() {
        self.viewDelegate?.loggedIn()
    }
}
```